# js get property names from ES6 class without instantiating

Tags: javascript

I am building tables from classes. I therefore loop all properties to generate the headers:

```
class User{
   name = null;
   age = null;
}

headerProps = Object.keys(new User());
```

Is it possible to do this without creating an instance of user?

Comment: No, because the properties don't exist anywhere until you create an instance.  The only way I could see you been able to is by parsing, eg. say use babel and look at the AST.

Comment: Since this is really just syntactical sugar for `function User() { this.name ... }`, I'll say *probably not* with the asterisk that there may be some magic in native ES6 somehow…

Comment: Just a side note - setting properties this way is not actually part of ES6 classes. This is part of a proposal for next versions of ES. Babel supports it already, but it may change in the future, so I wouldn't build anything with them yet.

Comment: @Chris  Maybe you can do something like this https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/2204/

Comment: What do you mean by "*I am building tables from classes*"? What is your [actual problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)?